# .Net Core Cant read connection string from appsettings.json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm currently creating a Web Api in .net core 2.0 and I simply cant get my connection string to work.

I've put my connectionstring into appsettings.json and load it in startup.cs

Appsettings.json

```
{
"Logging": {
"IncludeScopes": false,
"Debug": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning"
  }
},
"Console": {
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning"
  }
},
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DatabaseConnection": "Data Source=VMDEVSLN-EOE\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=EmployeeDB;Integrated Security=True"
  }
 }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

DbContext

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<CustomerTB> CustomerTB { get; set; }
}
```

I believe the problem lies somewhere in my appsettings.json but I just cant find it

Comment: What if you change `Configuration.GetConnectionString("DatabaseConnection");`to 
 `Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnection"]`

Comment: Still the same error. Doesnt solve it :(

Comment: Can you set break point if the connection string is taken from appSettings?

Comment: I did set a break point. It shows var connection = null

Comment: Put a breakpoint on "Configuration" and check if the connection string is in the data of one of the providers

Comment: Try to move appsettings.json to sln directory

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your `ConnectionStrings` section is inside the `Logging` section, I don't know if that's what you meant but anyway you can access the `DatabaseConnection` like this:

```
var connection = Configuration["Logging:ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnection"];
```

Comment: That is an awesome spot.

Comment: Thanks, it took me a few minutes to figured it out.

Comment: @KirkLarkin : Technically nothing wrong with "Logging:ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnection" but ConnectionStrings should be sibling of Logging and not child of it so that you can access it using ConnectionStrings:DatabaseConnection.

Comment: THANK YOU!

I didnt notice that "DatabaseConnection" was a child of "Logging"  instead of a sibling :D 
It works now

Comment: I've spent hours on this then came across this, and doh I did the same thing! Thanks.

Comment: Man ... i got victimized by this too!

Comment: 'Configuration' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.
How to specify the correct context?

Answer (score 0):

In asp.net core 1.x you should read settings through `ConfigurationBuilder`. In `Startup.cs`

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
        .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables();
    Configuration = builder.Build();
}
```

It could be the same approach in asp.net core 2.

Comment: This didnt fix the problem aswell :(